# Как сделать считывание роли участника командой?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я пытался сделать что-то с помощью вот этого кода:

```
member = ctx.message.author
    member_roles = member.roles
```

Но мне выходит ошибка:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

как исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Скинь полный код команды, которую ты делаешь

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
roleid=id роли на проверку
if get(ctx.author.roles, id=roleid):
    #роль имеется
else:
    #роли нет
```